# A continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I want to know whether the following statement is true. If $X$ is a continuous random variable and $f$ is 1-1 on the range of $X,$ then $f(X)$ is a continuous random variable. If it is true, could you tell me the way to prove it?

Comment: Is $f$ continuous (or even measurable?)

Comment: If f is measurable, it is true?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. For a counterexample, let $\Omega=[0,1]$, $\mathcal F=\mathcal B([0,1])$, $X(\omega)=\omega$, and $f(x) = x\chi_E -x\chi_{E^c}$ where $E\subset[0,1]$ is not (Borel)-measurable. Then $(0,1)$ is a measurable set but $f^{-1}(0,1)$ is not measurable.

In general, given a random variable $X$ and a real-valued function $f$, the composite function $f\circ X$ is a random variable if $f$ is measurable (although this is not a necessary condition, as @drhab pointed out in the comments). This follows from the measurability of the composition of measurable functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some question. Let $X$ be a continuous random variable. I know if $f$ is strictly monotone, then $f(X)$ is a continuous random variable. What is the general case of $f$  such that $f(X)$ is a continuous random variable?

Comment: "only if" is not correct. If e.g. $X$ is constant then $f\circ X$ is also constant (hence measurable). No conditions on $f$ are needed in this special case.

Comment: @drhab Good point, I revised the answer to only include nondegenerate random variables.

Comment: @WassyMam It is also true when $f$ is piecewise monotone, cf. http://ms.mcmaster.ca/canty/teaching/stat743/Lectures2.pdf

Comment: The condition that $X$ is not degenerate (still) does not justify "only if". Also if e.g. $X$ has a countable range then function $f\circ X$ will be measurable if $X$ is measurable. This is only an example and you cannot save "only if" by demanding that the range of $X$ is uncountable. Just drop "only if", I would say.

Answer (score 1):

Under the extra condition that $f$ is measurable the answer is: "yes".

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ denote the range of $X$.

It is to be shown that for each constant $c$ we have $\mathbb P\left(\left\{ f\left(X\right)=c\right\} \right)=0$.

Note that $\{f(X)=c\}=\{X\in f^{-1}(\{c\}\}=\{X\in A\cap f^{-1}(\{c\}\}$.

Assume that $\mathbb P\left(\left\{ f\left(X\right)=c\right\} \right)>0$
or equivalently that $\mathbb P\left(\left\{ X\in A\cap f^{-1}\left(\left\{ c\right\} \right)\right\} \right)>0$.

Since $X$ is a continuous random variable this can only be true if
$A\cap f^{-1}\left(\left\{ c\right\} \right)$ contains more than
one element.

However, this contradicts that $f$ is one-to-one on $A$.